# Test Works in PyCharm Community and Fails in Professional

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I switched to PyCharm Professional in hopes of using the code coverage tool, but it seems to have broken my test configuration. I have a project with a project folder, config folder and test folder like so:

```
\project
    \my_python_app
    \test
    \config\config.yml
```

In Pycharm Community, I was able to set the test path to the `\test` folder and the working directory to `\project`, which allowed me to access the config file. But when I switched to pro, it broke and said

`ImportError: Start directory is not importable: '/home/project/test'`

I need the working directory set to '\project' in order to access the config file. Any ideas on why this would be happening or suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Pycharms importing behaviour can be quite annoying, I had similar problems in the past. I could resolve then using the "Source Folder" setting in the project structure tabs. E.g. set the whole project folder (and maybe test) as "Source".